# Image messes up jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently making a website, and all of the other jquery functions work. However, when I add a picture to my html, it messes up the functions and makes them choppy. Here are a snippets of the html, css, and js.

html:

```
<section id="landing-page">
    <div class="center">
        <div id="image-background"></div>
        <div class="center-image">
            <img src="img/jasonbain-01.png"alt class="abs jasonbain">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
#landing-page {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #088da5;
height: 1280px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
    top: 700px;
}
.center-image {
position: relative;
top: -415px;
left: 275px;
height: 500px;
width: 800px;
}
.jasonbain {
height: 500px;
width: 800px;
position: relative;
top: -415px;
left: 275px;
height: 500px;
width: 800px;
}
#image-background {
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
background-color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 500px;
-webkit-border-radius: 500px;
border-radius: 500px;
position: relative;
top: 700px;
left: 425px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #003366;
}
```

js:

```
var main=function() {
    $("#landing-page").delay(5500).animate({"top": "0px"},200);
    $("#image-background").delay(5500).animate({"top": "70px"},100).animate({"top": "85px"},250).animate({"top": "80px"},300);
    $(".center-image").hide().delay(5700).fadeIn("slow");
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: What exactly was the function supposed to do originally?

Comment: <img src="img/jasonbain-01.png"alt class="abs jasonbain"> is not valid HTML. remove the word alt or use alt="something"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xo5xnvv/) if you remove your `alt class="abs jasonbain"`. Even with the invalid `alt` included it works fine. Your added classes on the image mess up the effect. Try it out yourself on the fiddle page.

```
<section id="landing-page">
    <div class="center">
        <div id="image-background"></div>
        <div class="center-image">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS

```
var main=function() {
    $("#landing-page").delay(5500).animate({"top": "0px"},200);
    $("#image-background").delay(5500).animate({"top": "70px"},100).animate({"top": "85px"},250).animate({"top": "80px"},300);
    $(".center-image").hide().delay(5700).fadeIn("slow");
}
main();
```

Comment: Hey, after trying it out with my original photo, I see that that image itself is actually the problem. It makes the function non-responsive for some reason. Are there any remedies to that obstacle? Or should I try a different image?